# Bypass code to insert cell values where cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following listed in my Sheet 1 code, moving cell values to the body of an Outlook email.

I'm trying to STOP inserting text for the given line if the cell in Column A is empty.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Create email with attachment, subject, and list of email addresses
ThisWorkbook.Save
Dim outlookApp As Object
Dim myMail As Object
Dim Source_File, to_emails, cc_emails As String
Dim file_to_send As String
Dim body_code As String
Dim i As Integer

Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

For i = 2 To 22
    to_emails = to_emails & Cells(i, 13) & ";"
    'for CC: change the 13 to whatever column count from the left where your CC list is
    'cc_emails = cc_emails & Cells(i, 13) & ";"
Next i

Source_File = ThisWorkbook.FullName
myMail.Attachments.Add Source_File

'myMail.CC = cc_emails
myMail.To = to_emails
myMail.Subject = Range("Q2").Value & " 10-8 Form " & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")

myMail.Body = Range("B2") & " Shift" & "  -  " & Format(Date, "mmmm dd, yyyy") _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Sergeant: " & Range("A6") & ", " & Range("B6") & vbNewLine & "          Status: " & Range("C6") _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Corporal: " & Range("A8") & ", " & Range("B8") & vbNewLine & "          Status: " & Range("C8") _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Assigned Deputies" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    Range("A10") & ", " & Range("B10") & vbNewLine & "          Assignment/Zone: " & Range("C10") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("A11") & ", " & Range("B11") & vbNewLine & "          Assignment/Zone: " & Range("C11") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("A12") & ", " & Range("B12") & vbNewLine & "          Assignment/Zone: " & Range("C12") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("A13") & ", " & Range("B13") & vbNewLine & "          Assignment/Zone: " & Range("C13") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("A14") & ", " & Range("B14") & vbNewLine & "          Assignment/Zone: " & Range("C14") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("A15") & ", " & Range("B15") & vbNewLine & "          Assignment/Zone: " & Range("C15") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("A16") & ", " & Range("B16") & vbNewLine & "          Assignment/Zone: " & Range("C16") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("A17") & ", " & Range("B17") & vbNewLine & "          Assignment/Zone: " & Range("C17") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("A18") & ", " & Range("B18") & vbNewLine & "          Assignment/Zone: " & Range("C18")

myMail.Display
ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest that you post the complete code

Comment: I'm sorry,  I was editing it.  Was this enough to see what you needed?

Comment: I think you'd receive better answers if you post the complete code

Comment: I'm only trying to change the "range" stuff at the bottom to keep it from adding " Assignment/Zone" at the end if the cells in Column A don't have any text in them, and then continue with the remaining code after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely break up that huge wall of text you have. This can be done with a loop.

Let's use a `For` loop here.

```vb
Dim concatString as String

For i = 10 To 18
    If Not Cells(i, "A").Text = vbNullString Then
         'Add to growing string
         concatString = concatString + Cells(i, "A").Text & ", " & Cells(i, "B").Text & vbCr
         concatString = concatString + "Assignment/Zone: " & Cells(i, "C").Text & vbCr
    End If
Next i
```

If column A contains an empty string, we skip over it and move to the next row.

I posted this  before you added more code, but I think you get the idea. Break up the huge chunk of code, and put only one cycle through columns A, B, and C in the loop. Adjust your loop constraints as necessary.

Here's what it would look like in your code:

```vb
'...
'your code here
'...

Dim concatString as String

For i = 10 To 18
    If Not Cells(i, "A").Text = vbNullString Then
         'Add to growing string
         concatString = concatString + Cells(i, "A").Text & ", " & Cells(i, "B").Text & vbCr
         concatString = concatString + "Assignment/Zone: " & Cells(i, "C").Text & vbCr
    End If
Next i

myMail.Body = Range("B2") & " Shift" & "  -  " & Format(Date, "mmmm dd, yyyy") _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Sergeant: " & Range("A6") & ", " & Range("B6") & vbNewLine & "          Status: " & Range("C6") _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Corporal: " & Range("A8") & ", " & Range("B8") & vbNewLine & "          Status: " & Range("C8") _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Assigned Deputies" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & concatString
```

I removed all those extra spaces, not sure if you actually need them in there or if it's a vestige of copying/pasting from VBE.

Comment: My initial answer was a misinterpretation of the question. I've edited it so that it will continue on to the next `i`, instead of finishing the loop completely.

Comment: If you've used my answer and it works, please mark it as "accepted" and/or vote on it for future users who have the same or similar questions!

Comment: Done! I will post the completed code as an "answer (my) question" to show other users the fix.  I still have some work to do formatting the text that's pasted, but this really got me over the hump!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code, the one that finally did it. Thank you to jclasley

```
`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Create email with attachment, subject, and list of email addresses
ThisWorkbook.Save
Dim outlookApp As Object
Dim myMail As Object
Dim Source_File, to_emails, cc_emails As String
Dim file_to_send As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim concatString As String

Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

For i = 2 To 22
    to_emails = to_emails & Cells(i, "M") & ";"
    'for CC: change the 13 to whatever column count from the left where your CC list is
    'cc_emails = cc_emails & Cells(i, 13) & ";"
Next i

Source_File = ThisWorkbook.FullName
myMail.Attachments.Add Source_File

'myMail.CC = cc_emails
myMail.To = to_emails
myMail.Subject = Range("Q2").Value & " 10-8 Form " & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")

For i = 10 To 18
    If Not Cells(i, "A").Text = vbNullString Then
         'Add to growing string
         concatString = concatString + Cells(i, "A").Text & ", " & Cells(i, "B").Text & vbCr
         concatString = concatString + "Assignment/Zone: " & Cells(i, "C").Text & vbNewLine & vbCr
    End If
Next i

myMail.Body = Range("B2") & " Shift" & "  -  " & Format(Date, "mmmm dd, yyyy") _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Sergeant: " & Range("A6") & ", " & Range("B6") & vbNewLine & "          Status: " & Range("C6") _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Corporal: " & Range("A8") & ", " & Range("B8") & vbNewLine & "          Status: " & Range("C8") _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Assigned Deputies" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & concatString

myMail.Display
ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

```
enter code here
```